# How should I return usernames instead of id inside Django Rest Framework API?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, rest, class

This is my model.

```
class FollowerModelSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    user = CharField(source='slug')

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['user', 'followers']
```

This is the serializer.

```
class FollowerModelViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FollowerModelSerializer
    allowed_methods = ('GET', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS')

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.queryset = self.queryset.filter(id=request.user.id)
        return super(FollowerModelViewSet, self).list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

And this is the API.

This is the response :

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

[
    {
        "user": "pop",
        "followers": [
            1,
            4
        ]
    }
]
```

Problem: It's returning the IDs of the followers. How should I make it return the usernames of the followers instead?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: @AMC: I think the OP wants the `followers` to be a list `"followers": ["username1", "username2"]`.

Comment: @testuser1: can you add *expected output* to the question?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem _I think the OP wants the followers to be a list "followers": ["username1", "username2"]_ I got that part, it just isn't clear what the problem or obstacle is.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem is absolutely correct. That's all I need right now, instead of ID, I just need the usernames. I've posted all the code that corresponds to this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with a [**`SlugRelatedField`** [drf-doc]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield):

```
class FollowerModelSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    user = CharField(source='slug')
    followers = SlugRelatedField(
        slug_field='username',
        many=True,
        read_only=True
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['user', 'followers']
```

This will thus use the `username` of the objects contained in the `followers` relation.

Comment: Oh shit, that's all I needed. A slug related field. I sure do feel stupid for not knowing about it earlier. Thanks a whole lot though!